# Python's create_default_context() equivalent in Go?

Tags: ssl, go, ssl-certificate

I'm trying to modify my Go client and server code to use TLS. In Python I can do `ssl.create_default_context(purpose=ssl.Purpose.SERVER_AUTH)`
which will automatically load the system's trusted CA certs and uses secure settings. I'm wondering if there's something similar in Go where it will automatically load trusted CA certificates. I'm not sure exactly what to put for the client's certificates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're looking for [`tls.Config`](https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/tls/#Config). But keep in mind that Python's `ssl.create_default_context` exposes a lot of SSL internals that most people don't need, and you might not need a `tls.Config` in your application at all. For instance, `net/http` has a [`http.ListenAndServeTLS()`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#ListenAndServeTLS) function which starts a TLS web server with sensible defaults and whatever certificates you provide.

Comment: In addition, on the client-side of things Go will load the system CAs by default and verify the server against them; no special code required.

Comment: tls.Config{} with no initialization worked perfectly for what I needed.